# How do you find the last non-zero number in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently writing a console program in C++ for interpreting Chip-8 code, and I need to address the stack, requiring me to find the last non-zero entry in the stack array.

Comment: Start at the end of the array and work through it backwards until you reach a non-zero value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your stack is something like `std::array<int>` you can do:

```
auto rit = std::find_if(std::crbegin(my_stack), std::crend(my_stack),
    [](int v) { return v; });
auto idx = std::distance(std::cbegin(my_stack), rit.base()) - 1;
```

[Here is a live example.](https://ideone.com/JLo3dF)